# In Express.js, how can I render a Jade partial-view without a "response" object?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Using Express.js, I'd like to render a partial-view from a Jade template to a variable.

Usually, you render a partial-view directly to the response object:

```
response.partial('templatePath', {a:1, b:2, c:3})
```

However, since I'm inside a Socket.io server event, I don't have the "response" object.

Is there an elegant way to render a Jade partial-view to a variable **without** using the response object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can manually compile the Jade template.

```
var jade = require('jade');
var template = require('fs').readFileSync(pathToTemplate, 'utf8');
var jadeFn = jade.compile(template, { filename: pathToTemplate, pretty: true });
var renderedTemplate = jadeFn({data: 1, hello: 'world'});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I used the following to resolve pathToTemplate: 
var pathToTemplate = require('path').resolve(__dirname, '../views') + templateName + '.jade';

Comment: Thank you very much! I had this problem trying to fit a partial, and your answer was the first result in google. You Rock man!

Comment: This answer is correct **but if you want to use cache mechanism** check [matthias response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644580/in-express-js-how-can-i-render-a-jade-partial-view-without-a-response-object#answer-12725703)

Comment: Just re-use `jadeFn` (in a loop for example) and it will make use of the cached template.

Answer (score 14):

Here's the straight solution to this problem for *express 3* users (which should be widely spread now):

res.partial() has been removed but you can always use **app.render() using the callback function**, if the response object is not part of the current context like in Liors case:

```
app.render('templatePath', {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
},function(err,html) {
  console.log('html',html);
  // your handling of the rendered html output goes here
});
```

Since app.render() is a function of the express app object it's naturally aware of the configured template engine and other settings. It behaves the same way as the specific res.render() on app.get() or other express request events.

See also:

- http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.render for app.render()
- https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x for express 2.x > 3.x migration purposes

Comment: This way is better because of using cache? A I right? @matthias **correct me if I'a wrong** ??

Comment: As far as I remember, (compiled) jade templates are cached under production environments (NODE_ENV="production"), so that's true. On the other hand, with @emostars manual read-from-fs-and-compile approach you're flexible enough to control caching behavior yourself, e.g. reuse ```jadeFn``` without the need to re-read or re-compile the original jade template string.