# load partial html with nodeJS & Jade throughout AJAX calls

Tags: html, node.js, pug

Is there a clean way to load only a part of a page using nodeJs and Jade?:

In fact I am building a music blog and I would like to have a continuous player on the top of each page of my site. I don't want the player to stop and restart each time I click on a link on my website.

I think this could be achieved by creating a global "frame" page that contains the player and the menu of my website and that gets loaded only once and then using AJAX calls to load the content of each page of the site.

Do you think it is the right approach (to have a continuous player)? 
Is there a clean way with Jade and nodeJS to transfer partial html page throughout AJAX calls?

Comment: There are many ways to do it, and "right" approach is very subjective.

Comment: Also, you can render Jade this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12725703/95190

Comment: I think that app.render reloads the page. No?

Comment: Please take a closer look at the answer I linked to. It has nothing to do with reloading the page. You asked if there's a way to render portions of a web page. It just emits html, which you could then retrieve from the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PJAX http://pjax.heroku.com/ 
http://ntotten.com/2012/04/09/building-super-fast-web-apps-with-pjax/
 load only a part of a page